# Is it necessary to Dispose on Application_End if it's ending anyway?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, autofac

When dealing with an IOC container like Autofac in a Web or Api solution, you see a lot of implimentation code like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ///etc..
    this.container = builder.Build();//returns IDisposable instance
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    //etc..
}

protected void Application_End()
{
    container.Dispose();
}
```

See that on Application_End the container is being disposed explicitly.

Great, but is that really necessary?

- Aren't we talking about a web application that is about to end in any
  case?
- Surely, that means that Dispose will be called for ALL
  un-Disposed objects still kicking around?
- Is there any valid reason
  or benefit for calling the dispose explicitly in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Great, but is that really necessary?

Yes, that's the best practice. Dispose all IDisposable instances when you finish.

> Aren't we talking about a web application that is about to end in any
>   case? 
>   Surely, that means that Dispose will be called for ALL un-Disposed objects still kicking around? 
>   Is there any valid reason or benefit for calling the dispose explicitly in this way?

The advantage is, Disposing will suppress the finalization (if you container has a implemented finalization). So, the garbage collector will dispose it sooner as it doesn't have to go to the finalization queue.

**Note:**

And also note that when you are disposing Autofac `LifetimeScope`, it will execute the `Dispose` for all of it IDisposable instances. For instance, if you have created your `container` using Autofac and you are disposing the Autofac's `LifeTimeScope` when you finish, you may not have to Dispose the `container` manually.

Comment: .NET will run all finalizers for undisposed objects when the application ends, so disposing those instances to do proper finalization is not needed.